# Print array values above a certain value

Tags: java, arrays

The method I'm building should print all values above the average values in the method.
I have built the method to calculate the average and then print only the values above that amount.

However it prints the values that are positive.

```
int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < intList.length; i++)
    {
        total += intList[i]; 
        {
            if (intList[i] > intList[total]) 
            {
                System.out.println(intList[i] + "\t");
            }
        }
    }


    return total;
```

How do I make it so instead of printing all positives it prints only the values in the array above the average value in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] values = new int[] { 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8 };

    double sum = 0;
    for (int value : values)
        sum += value;

    double avg = sum / values.length;

    System.out.printf("AVG = %.2f\n----------\n", avg);

    for (int value : values) {
        if (value > avg)
            System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
AVG = 4.50
----------
5
6
7
8
```

Comment: right now your avg is being calculated using integer division which will lead to precision error

Comment: @user2573153 i was to say the same, it's exactly like my answer but using average with int

Answer (score 3):

You need two different loops. One to add all the numbers together to get the total. Then you need to get the average from that total. Then loop again to check and print

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop 2 times, one for calculating average and then when you get total calculated you have to change if comparision. `intList[i] > intList[total]` to `intList[i] > total`

Example :

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int[] intList = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int total = 0;
    // first loop calculate 
    for (int i : intList){
      total += i; 
    }

    double average = total / (double)intList.length;//take care array can't be empty.

    System.out.println("average :"+ average);    

    //then show 
    for(int i : intList){
        if (i > average){
          System.out.println(i + "\t");
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers above nailed it, your second loop isn't comparing it to the average, rather the total. You need one loop first to get the average of the array, and then a second one to test the array against the average.

```
for (int i = 0;i < array.count; i++){
    total = total + array[i]
}
average = total / array.count
for (int i = 0;i < array.count; i++){
    if (array[i]>total){
       print
    }
}
```

Theres some pseudocode/ish to get you going.